# Graphic displayed while copying files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

When you copy a folder with lots of file from one location to another, a chunky dialog like the following is displayed:

[image: Windows 10 copy files dialog]

This appears to add a substantial amount of time to the copy process. I compared copying 15,000 files (a mixture of small and large) from one folder to another via Explorer (using the above graphic) and the command prompt (using `xcopy *.* DEST-FOLDER /q`).

From right-click `Paste` to completion using Explorer took an average of 23.56s (if you subtract the time Windows pauses while "discovering files", this reduces to 16.25s). Same operation from the command prompt took an average of 8.32s. Three iterations in each case.

This graphic and the constant updating of the `Name` label appears to be the bottleneck. Just pointless eye candy.

Can Windows 10 be configured to show a simpler, faster graphic, perhaps something like the one from Windows XP or 7?

Comment: Just how did you test/time this and how thoroughly was your test (number of iterations etc)? And did you time this in both cases (as in not just the command line one compared to the estimation showed in the dialog)? I'm not necessarily saying you're wrong about anything, these questions just seem mandatory to me.

Comment: Fair comment @notjustme, thanks. Experiments done and question updated with details.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer cannot be configured (even less today than in 2018).
Using a better file-manager is the only option

As regarding file copying, Windows Explorer is just about the slowest
file copier on Windows.
For copying large amount of data, it's better to use a free third-party product.

The fastest I know is
[FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/),
but you may try others.
See the article
[Best Free File Copy Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-copy-utility.htm).

None of these utilities shows a beautiful progress pop-up display as does
Windows Explorer.